# Nothing happens when I try to send files / folders to Compressed (zipped) folder

Tags: dll, zip, compression, directory, ocx

For a while now, I've been unable to send files or folders to Zipped folder from windows explorer.  The option is there, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

It seems others have had similar problems, but in their cases, the option has been greyed out, or another program has taken over as the default `.zip` program.

If I type `"regsvr32 %windir%/system32/zipfldr.dll"` into a run command, I get the following error:

```
_______________________________

[Window Title]
RegSvr32

[Content]
The module "C:\WINDOWS/system32/zipfldr.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "C:\WINDOWS/system32/zipfldr.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

[OK]
_______________________________
```

Very annoying, I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No but this problem did sort itself out in the end.  I do remember it reoccurring once though.

Comment: I just used 7-zip - free and did the job

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. However my fix was much easier. My file names and paths were too long to be zipped. There was no warning.

I resolved it by copy-pasting the directory to another with a shorter path.

e.g. from `/this/path/is/way/too/ooo/ooo/oo/long` to `/home/Desktop`

Comment: Why is there no warning message for such a simple reason!

Comment: I just had same problem on windows 10. Your solution worked. Amazing that no message is given to the user telling them why the zip did not start. This is from a company that has been around for 40 years making software. Yet they can't figure how to make an error message.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, when clicked on send to compressed file nothing happened, then i found out that when you have a deep folder structure, windows fails to zip and doesn't show any errors. As it is explained here: http://david-homer.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/when-using-send-to-compressed-zipped.html

Comment: You should explain it here, because this link can sooner or later be unavailable, in that case your answer could be not helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I've copied the comments from this link mentioned earlier - http://david-homer.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/when-using-send-to-compressed-zipped.html

> #### When using the "Send to compressed (zipped) folder" context menu item nothing happens
>
> I've recently had a problem when using the "Send to
> compressed (zipped) folder" context menu item nothing happens on
> Windows 8.1.
>
> Looking further into this I found that it worked most folders just not
> the one I wanted to ZIP.
>
> After a while I realised that I had a Visual Studio project source
> code in this folder that had that annoying deep object folder problem and it
> seems that when you click "Send to compressed (zipped) folder" if
> there is an exceptionally deep directory structure in the folder you
> are zipping, the compression may fail but show no error.
>
> I use the following tried and tested RoboCopy method for removing
> these broken directories with exceptionally deep paths that you can't
> delete with Windows Explorer.
>
> ```
> @echo off
> cls
> mkdir emptyfolder
> robocopy emptyfolder "path\to\obj" /MIR
> rmdir emptyfolder
> rmdir "path\to\obj"
> pause
> ```
>
> Why not check out our User Provisioning Tool on our web site

I can see that this could be a potential problem, however at the moment this is working fine again as far as I can see - if I have the issue again I guess I'll have to check out the file structure, maybe that could be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is way too late but it might help someone. Does your folder have other sub-folders inside it? In my case, I tried zipping the folders which have sub-folders and it did not work (no response just like in your case). Try to zip the folders which have files only and no any sub folders inside.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your file does not have the extension. Remember that Windows explorer does not allow creating folders beginning with dot, even though the underlying system can handle them.

Comment: That's helpful to know, thanks.  But the files do not begin with a dot.  Whether i right click > Send to > Zipped file, or whether i go to Share > Zip, neither seems to work.  They aren't greyed out, and they highlight when clicked, but nothing happens.  So strange...

Answer (score 2):

I realise that I'm quite late to answering this question but I was having the same problem when trying to zip a folder and it seemed that nothing happened and no error was shown.

I right clicked and copied the folder, then pasted it to the same directory, during the copy a dialog told me there were several files in the folder that where too long to be copied, so I clicked skip. Then right clicked the copied folder and sent to zip and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this problem while I was attempting to zip Android Studio Source code from 10 different projects. Initially having a overly deep structure seemed to be the case, and for me too Windows did not show an error initially.

So I did some more file digging and I found that this error usually occurs if you have an empty folder somewhere in your file structure of the file you are trying to zip. Each level down I was able to find the folder containing the mystery folder and each time the windows error would appear showing me the error saying that it could not zip an empty folder!

I went down the Rabbit hole and added a simple READ_ME.*txt file to each empty folder and viola!

I am using Windows 10 updated version on 10.2018.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Also way late, but maybe this will help others:

I had this problem, but could not find this mysterious folder, or deep directory, in fact, one of the folders that wouldn't zip had just one Word document in it.

What I did was to find a folder that would zip (or create one) and then copy the folder that wouldn't zip into it.

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

I worked around the problem by using 7-Zip instead.